# What is the most efficient and the clean way to compare two integers in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, comparison

Two variables

```
int x, y;
```

are going to be compared and the greater of them is going to be assigned to another variable,

```
int greatest;
```

The first thing that comes to mind is

```
if (x > y) { greatest = x; }
else { greatest = y; }
```

Is there any other way that is much more *efficient and clever*?

Comment: You want it to be human readable. Let the compiler take care of efficiency.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Please don't post answers in the comment section.

Comment: More efficient — unlikely.  Terser: `int greatest = (x > y) ? x : y;` — but the computation (object code) is unlikely to be any different.

Comment: @Dharman — at 16 characters including the back quotes, that's only one character over the minimum required to be a comment.  An answer it is not, therefore, and Yoda am I neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard header [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) provides the standard function [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). One of the overloads for this function compares two objects and returns a reference to the largest of the two. In your case, the expression would be :

```
auto greatest = std::max(x, y)
```

If there is a "most efficient" way to get the largest of the two you, you should rely on the underlying implementation to use it for you. `std::max` should implement the best way of doing it. But even if you are using a weak standard library implementation that doesn't, the compiler should still catch this and optimize it.

Remember that in c++ your code describes a behavior. It is not a list of instructions that the compiler will execute verbatim. Your code will be transformed by the compiler to implement these micro optimizations for you where they are known to exist.